# How to find the origin of a TensorFlow NaN error on a Multi GPU system with NVIDIA Tesla P100 GPUs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

## Baseline situation

I train on a GPU cluster with 8 NVIDIA Tesla P100 GPUs. The script code is based on the TensorFlow Tutorial [Convolutional Neural Networks](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/). As training data I create binary files based on the [Cifar10 data set](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html), which contain only 5000 of the 50,000 images. I use only one of these files per training session.

Here are some basic data about the training:

- Epoch: 100,000
- Batch size: 128
- Number of training data: 5,000
- Init learning rate: 0.1
- Learning rate decay factor: 0.1
- Number of Epochs per decay 350.0
- No exponential moving average
- ...
- If you need more information please comment

The problem is, if I do the training with more than one GPU, I get a NaN error sooner or later. The loss value then explodes within a few epochs from `~0.4` to values above `~1.e+26` to infinity I think and then comes the NaN error.

## What have I done so far

So far I have tried the following to identify the origin of the NaN bug, so that I can fix it.

- I added `tf.check_numerics()` after almost every return of a tensor. (Error messages are below)
- I added `tf.add_check_numerics_ops()`. The error messages are as incomprehensible to me as those of `tf.check_numerics()` :-)
- I checked the input data for NaN, data are okay.
- I have reduced the learning rate, so the error comes later.

  - Init learning rate: 0.01
  - Learning rate decay factor: 0.01
- Run simpleP2P (Cuda Examples) and passed the test. (Output are below)
- Modified the [TensorFlow Tutorial Code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L158) only so far that the `tf.train.string_input_producer()` gets only 1 file instead of 5 files. `filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([/path/traindata.bin])` And set number of training data to 5,000.
- To save the variables instead of cpu:0 (see TensorFlow Tutorial [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py#L109) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L141)) on gpu:0 and to train only with gpu: 1-7. But that was so slow it wasn't an option and I broke it off. (Maybe I did it wrong, too)
- Only train with 4 GPUs, (0-3 or 4-7), but the NaN error came later.

## System

- Linux kernel: 4.4.72-18.12-default x86_64
- 8x NVIDIA Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB
- Cuda 8.0 - V8.0.61
- TenserFlow 1.4.1
- Python3

## Some code and error messages

`tf.check_numerics()` error message:

```
2018..: E tensorflow/core/kernels/check_numerics_op.cc:157] abnormal_detected_host @0x12e49401900 = {0, 1} NaN: cnn()conv2
2018..: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:303] _3_prefetch_queue/fifo_queue: Skipping cancelled dequeue attempt with queue not closed
2018..: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:303] _3_prefetch_queue/fifo_queue: Skipping cancelled dequeue attempt with queue not closed
2018..: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:303] _3_prefetch_queue/fifo_queue: Skipping cancelled dequeue attempt with queue not closed
2018..: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:303] _3_prefetch_queue/fifo_queue: Skipping cancelled dequeue attempt with queue not closed
2018..: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:303] _3_prefetch_queue/fifo_queue: Skipping cancelled dequeue attempt with queue not closed
2018..: E tensorflow/core/kernels/check_numerics_op.cc:157] abnormal_detected_host @0x12e49401a00 = {0, 1} NaN: cnn()conv2
2018..: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: NaN: cnn()conv2 : Tensor had Inf values
     [[Node: tower_5/conv2/CheckNumerics_3 = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="NaN: cnn()conv2", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:5"](tower_5/conv2/conv2)]]
2018-01-19 17:31:30.439453: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: NaN: cnn()conv2 : Tensor had Inf values
     [[Node: tower_5/conv2/CheckNumerics_3 = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="NaN: cnn()conv2", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:5"](tower_5/conv2/conv2)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: NaN: cnn()conv2 : Tensor had Inf values
     [[Node: tower_7/conv2/CheckNumerics_3 = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="NaN: cnn()conv2", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:7"](tower_7/conv2/conv2)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn_base.py", line 1703, in <module>
    training()
  File "cnn_base.py", line 1314, in training
    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: NaN: cnn()conv2 : Tensor had Inf values
     [[Node: tower_7/conv2/CheckNumerics_3 = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="NaN: cnn()conv2", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:7"](tower_7/conv2/conv2)]]

Caused by op 'tower_7/conv2/CheckNumerics_3', defined at:
  File "cnn_base.py", line 1703, in <module>
    training()
  File "cnn_base.py", line 1228, in training
    loss = tower_loss(scope, image_batch, label_batch)
  File "cnn_base.py", line 1110, in tower_loss
    logits = cnn(images)
  File "cnn_base.py", line 1018, in cnn
    conv2 = tf.check_numerics(conv2, 'NaN: cnn()conv2')
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 569, in check_numerics
    "CheckNumerics", tensor=tensor, message=message, name=name)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): NaN: cnn()conv2 : Tensor had Inf values
     [[Node: tower_7/conv2/CheckNumerics_3 = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="NaN: cnn()conv2", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:7"](tower_7/conv2/conv2)]]
```

Sometimes the NaN error comes from `pool1`, `nom1`, `conv2`, ... or `local3`. But never from `x`. And not always the same GPU.

```
def cnn(x):
    #### NaN detect:
    if DEBUG_NAN:
        x = tf.check_numerics(x, 'NaN: cnn(x)')

    #conv1
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
        kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 3, 64], stddev=5e-2, wd=0.0)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
        conv1 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
        #### NaN detect:
        if DEBUG_NAN:
            conv1 = tf.check_numerics(conv1, 'NaN: cnn()conv1')

    # pool1
    pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')
    #### NaN detect:
    if DEBUG_NAN:
        pool1 = tf.check_numerics(pool1, 'NaN: cnn()pool1')

    # norm1
    norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(pool1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75, name='norm1')
    #### NaN detect:
    if DEBUG_NAN:
        norm1 = tf.check_numerics(norm1, 'NaN: cnn()norm1')

    # conv2
    with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
        kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 64, 64], stddev=5e-2, wd=0.0)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
        pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
        conv2 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
        #### NaN detect:
        if DEBUG_NAN:
            conv2 = tf.check_numerics(conv2, 'NaN: cnn()conv2')
    ...
    #norm2
    ...
    #pool2
    ...
    #local3
    ...
    #local4
    ...
    #linear layer
    ...
    return softmax_linear
```

The output of  simpleP2P:

```
[./simpleP2P] - Starting...
Checking for multiple GPUs...
CUDA-capable device count: 8
> GPU0 = "Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
> GPU1 = "Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
> GPU2 = "Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
> GPU3 = "Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
> GPU4 = "Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
> GPU5 = "Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
> GPU6 = "Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
> GPU7 = "Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)

Checking GPU(s) for support of peer to peer memory access...
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU2) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU3) : No
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU4) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU5) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU7) -> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU6) : Yes
Enabling peer access between GPU0 and GPU1...
Checking GPU0 and GPU1 for UVA capabilities...
> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU0) supports UVA: Yes
> Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (GPU1) supports UVA: Yes
Both GPUs can support UVA, enabling...
Allocating buffers (64MB on GPU0, GPU1 and CPU Host)...
Creating event handles...
cudaMemcpyPeer / cudaMemcpy between GPU0 and GPU1: 12.16GB/s
Preparing host buffer and memcpy to GPU0...
Run kernel on GPU1, taking source data from GPU0 and writing to GPU1...
Run kernel on GPU0, taking source data from GPU1 and writing to GPU0...
Copy data back to host from GPU0 and verify results...
Disabling peer access...
Shutting down...
Test passed
```

## Edit

I forgot the error message from `tf.add_check_numerics_ops()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: NaN: average_gradients(expanded_g) : Tensor had Inf and NaN values
         [[Node: CheckNumerics_30 = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="NaN: average_gradients(expanded_g)", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ExpandDims_30)]]
         [[Node: tower_6/total_loss/_2216 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:6", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4923_tower_6/total_loss", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:6"](tower_6/total_loss)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn_base.py", line 1704, in <module>
    training()
  File "cnn_base.py", line 1312, in training
    nan_debug, _, loss_value = sess.run([check_op, train_op, loss])
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: NaN: average_gradients(expanded_g) : Tensor had Inf and NaN values
         [[Node: CheckNumerics_30 = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="NaN: average_gradients(expanded_g)", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ExpandDims_30)]]
         [[Node: tower_6/total_loss/_2216 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:6", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4923_tower_6/total_loss", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:6"](tower_6/total_loss)]]


Caused by op 'CheckNumerics_30', defined at:
  File "cnn_base.py", line 1704, in <module>
    training()
  File "cnn_base.py", line 1241, in training
    grads = average_gradients(tower_grads)
  File "cnn_base.py", line 1142, in average_gradients
    expanded_g = tf.check_numerics(expanded_g, 'NaN: average_gradients(expanded_g)')
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 569, in check_numerics
    "CheckNumerics", tensor=tensor, message=message, name=name)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/freundlicher/tfEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): NaN: average_gradients(expanded_g) : Tensor had Inf and NaN values
         [[Node: CheckNumerics_30 = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="NaN: average_gradients(expanded_g)", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ExpandDims_30)]]
         [[Node: tower_6/total_loss/_2216 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:6", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4923_tower_6/total_loss", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:6"](tower_6/total_loss)]]
```

## Edit 2

The evolution of the error value just before the NaN error:

```
| Step: 71001 | Loss: 0.408
| Step: 71002 | Loss: 0.334
| Step: 71003 | Loss: 0.366
| Step: 71004 | Loss: 0.535
| Step: 71005 | Loss: 0.580
| Step: 71006 | Loss: 0.665
| Step: 71007 | Loss: 0.973
| Step: 71008 | Loss: 1.532
| Step: 71009 | Loss: 1.926
| Step: 71010 | Loss: 3.996
| Step: 71011 | Loss: 3.897
| Step: 71012 | Loss: 48.157
| Step: 71013 | Loss: 116.674
| Step: 71014 | Loss: 81.629
| Step: 71015 | Loss: 605.457
| Step: 71016 | Loss: 5922.730
| Step: 71017 | Loss: 44706.512
| Step: 71018 | Loss: 153461.141
| Step: 71019 | Loss: 3288852.750
| Step: 71020 | Loss: 100990616.000
| Step: 71021 | Loss: 191808240.000
| Step: 71022 | Loss: 198109808.000
| Step: 71023 | Loss: 644734183800832.000
| Step: 71024 | Loss: 10551573931360256.000
| Step: 71025 | Loss: 14357759286057107456.000
| Step: 71026 | Loss: 4102828570323191104191619661824.000
| Step: 71027 | Loss: nan
```

Comment: When you said `Tesla P100`, I just assumed you meant [the car](http://performancedrive.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Tesla-Model-S-P100D.jpg).  Probably not the same thing.

Comment: oh you right :) i change the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for the NaN's error. In retrospect, I have to say, it's been in front of my nose the whole time.

**The short version:**

I used the `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer()` with `tf.train.exponential_decay()` for the optimization. Changing it to `tf.train.AdamOptimizer()` solve my problem.

**The long version:**

So it wasn't the GPU cluster, but the optimization algorithm. But I didn't immediately notice that, because if I used only one GPU on the GPU cluster, the total loss values were not infinite but if I used several GPUs, the loss value added up and then went into the infinite range. Only when I ran the script on my local machine for a very long time (using a NVIDIA GTX 770) did I get a NaN error. That's when I knew it had nothing to do with the NVIDIA Tesla P100.  This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet/issues/143) caused me to get more involved with the `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer()`. Now it looks like that solved my problem.

The TensorFlow tutorial [Convolutional Neural Networks](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L161) use `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer()` and i change now the code from:

```
lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(get_initial_learning_rate(), 
        global_step, 
        decay_steps, 
        get_learning_rate_decay_factor(), 
        staircase=True)

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)
```

to:

```
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
get_initial_learning_rate(), # 0.001
beta1=0.9, 
beta2=0.999, 
epsilon=1e-08, 
use_locking=False)
```

Comment: why would multi-GPU and SGD result in nan but not Adam? if added loss goes to infinite, again what does it have to do with SGD?

Comment: The nan value results from the division by zero. Adam prevents this by adding a very small value to the denominator.

Comment: The zero results from the sum of all loss values which at some point can no longer be stored and becomes zero.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with dice loss. By the way I did not quite understand what do you mean by 'The zero results from the sum of all loss values which at some point can no longer be stored and becomes zero'?